# Share cookies between different hosts in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies, cross-domain

I have two MVC app hosted in localhost. i need to share cookie data to both web applications. URLs are http://localhost:53100/ and http://localhost:8100/ so on. One app is writing data to cookie second app is going to access it. Cookies are in localhost. But when i'm trying to access them from second app, they not exists. Can Someone help for this???

```
HttpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("CookieD", "Data1") { Domain = "localhost" });
```

Comment: What do you mean by *trying to access them*?

Comment: I need to read the cookie data. This thing is not working when i request from the outside of the domain

Comment: This should be fine, are you accessing the value using `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["CookieD"].Value;`?

Comment: However you cannot do cross domains, e.g. `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com` but you can use sub domains, `sub1.mydomain.com`, `sub2.mydomain.com`

Comment: Just for clarification - 1) you have two server applications - `A` and `B`, 2) both of them run on the same host `locahost` but different ports `53100` and `8100`, and 3) you have client application `X`, which sends request to first server `A`, 4) then `X` receive response from the `A` with cookie, 5) then the `X` sends another request with cookie (from previous step) to server `B`, 6) and your problem is that at this point `B` did not receive the cookie... right?

Comment: yeah that is the case. Need to add something. X sends request to B through the A

Comment: It would be useful if you **update your question accordingly** to state exactly what and where *is not working* and provide some code especially on how you are passing *requests from client through one server to the another*. That would be of service for others who may run into the same problem as you. (See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))